Do App Store Connect custom campaign links track subscription purchases and renewals?
Scenario: A user follows a custom campaign link to download my free app and purchase a subscription at $1 / month. That subscription renews a month later at the same price. Will this campaign link in analytics show $2 in proceeds?
